# Filtering Filenames with two or more file extensions

Tags: c#, string

i have thousend of filenames as strings and I want to filter the filenames with two or more file extensions in C#.

Example:

- pic.jpng
- pic_21.03.2007_.jpng
- manuel.pdf
- manuel.pdf.exe .... this one I want to filter!
- pic_3.jpng

How can in search for strings with two or more file extensions in the file name?

Comment: jpng! Congratulations, you have just invented a new image format! :-)

Comment: The first step is to determine what is and is not an extension. From your examples, "pdf" is an extension but "03" and "2007_" are not. So what is the rule that determines whether it's an extension?

Comment: A good rule might be: The last part is always an extension. Previous parts are only considered to be extensions if they don't contain numbers and if their length does does not exceed 4.

Comment: `yourList.Where(x => x.Spit('.').Length > 2).ToList();`

Comment: _if they don't contain numbers and if their length does does not exceed 4_ Sounds rather arbitrary. `track01.mp3.original`

Comment: Differentiating between "real" extensions and others seems adventurous anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If by file extensions you mean the number of periods in the filename, you can just count the '.' character in each filename. For example:

```
var myFilenames = new[] { "pic.jpng", "manuel.pdf", "manuel.pdf.exe" };
var twoOrMoreExtensions = myFilenames.Where(f => f.Count(x => x == '.') >= 2);
foreach (var filename in twoOrMoreExtensions)
{
    Console.WriteLine(filename);
}
```

Will write out:

> manuel.pdf.exe

As has been pointed out in the comments though, if you include `pic_21.03.2007_.jpng` this will have "3 extensions" based on that rule.